# Winform Slide Sorter Functionality

Tags: c#, winforms

I am looking for help with a program. The language is c# and it is a winform app. I am storing links to thumbnail images in a database. The images are kept in the file system as individual files. I need a way to browse those files.

Specifically, I need a control to give me functionality similar to the Slide Sorter found in presentation software such as OpenOffice Presenter and Microsoft PowerPoint. It doesn't seem that any of the standard windows controls would work. In case you do not know, the Slide Sorter is essentially a grid. The grid is made up of the series of thumbnail images and labels for those images. These images and their associated labels can be removed or reordered. Reordering is done by dragging the thumbnail and dropping it in the new position.

A solution was apparently found here: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/269058-need-slide-sorter-functionality but I do not understand it.

I found some useful information here: http://flylib.com/books/en/2.255.1.247/1/ However I am finding it hard to piece together. In particular how I would number images and add drag and drop support.

Having looked here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwjvR4tX790 I suspect I may need to use some kind of layout control but would be interested in any other approaches. This approach appears limited in terms of support for the drag-and-drop functionality that I need. Another approach might be to clone the items as shown here [Clone Controls - C# (Winform)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266589/clone-controls-c-sharp-winform?rq=1) again I am unsure how this would work with drag and drop.

I am open to both code solutions as well as advice on using a particular component - even if I have to buy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would defenitly go with the

> flylib.com

Solution with one alterations I would first make a custom control Container that has inside a PictureBox and a label both centered to the container but the insides should not be able to get focus so they are not clickable. And then just use the method discrybed in the link you provided and work from there.

For the mouse drag and drop you can hook up to the mouse events described in another question on this site [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459458/moveable-custom-control)

Comment: Can you please help explain to me what they are advocating at flylib?

Comment: well I would thake from that site that Panel would be for your case the most usable container option since you get ScrollBar's from it witch you would probably need.